# Modifying a global variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def OnClick1(self,event):
    song='maid.mp3'
    aplayer(song, play1 , 1, 0)
```

`play1` is a global variable that is modified in another module. But the value of `play1` is still the initial one which is `0`. How to format the variable `play1`?

Comment: def SetVal(self, event):
 global t0, t4
 state1 = str(self.rb1.GetValue())
 print state1
        state2 = str(self.rb2.GetValue())
 print state2
 state3 = str(self.rb3.GetValue())
 print state3
 state4 = str(self.rb4.GetValue())
 print state4
 if state1=="True":
  t0="audio2.mp3"
 if state2=="True":
  t0="audio1.mp3"
 if state3=="True":
  t4="audio2.mp3"
 if state4=="True":
  t4="audio1.mp3" Again the problem with the global variable. It says t0 and t4 are not defined. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding you question, but in Python global variables can be read, but not set, by default. If you want to modify the global variable you need to first declare it as global, then you can set it:

```
play1 = 1
def some_function():
    global play1
    play1 = #your value here, which will change the global value
```

If the problem is just that the other module isn't accessing the global variable (which it won't) you can try attaching the variable to the `__builtin__` module, so you can access or modify it from any module by just doing:

```
import __builtin__
__builtin__.play1 = #new value
```

That's it - it should now be a cross-module global variable.

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is, then. Where in your code are you modifying `play1`? Could you provide a more complete version of your code?

Comment: got the answer. I did it the other way round.

Comment: Got to say that the second way is not a pythonic at all. If you want aplayer to change `play1` You should do it with returned value: `play1 = aplayer(song,1,0)`